# Mule ActiveMQ JMS component with a receiver threading profile configuration not working

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

Is there any way to set a receiver threading profile configuration for an ActiveMQ connector component in Mule ESB? It seems that it's possible from the xsd but when I run the project, a `SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type` is thrown for the `receiver-threading-profile` element.

This is my activemq connector config

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <reconnect frequency="5000"/>
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="10" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working? Or how can I set a max amount of threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The child elements order matters, try with:

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" specification="1.1" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" disableTemporaryReplyToDestinations="true" doc:name="Active MQ">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="10" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <reconnect frequency="5000"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

Comment: lol david, you were right, is because of the xsd schema definition of the activemq-connector element, right?